# Target Lookaliks using Journey Builder (Advertising Studio)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, audience, advertising-studio

I want to use Journey Builder to only target the Lookalikes for new client acquisition. Is it possible? I don't see any option to create Lookalikes in journey builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mentioning which advertising method you are using, but let's assume Facebook. You can easily create an audience in Journey Builder, and when it is passed to Facebook Business Manager (as a custom audience) you can use it as a basis for creating a lookalike audience there.

1. Go to Audiences within your Ad Manager.
2. Choose a Custom Audience source. Select the audience which you have created in Journey Builder/Advertising Studio
3. Follow the instructions to create your Custom Audience based on the source you chose in Step 2.

Once you’ve created your Custom Audience, you can use it to set up a Lookalike Audience. Here are the steps to create a Facebook Lookalike Audience:

1. Select Create a Lookalike Audience within the Ad Manager.

[image]

2. Choose your source. Remember, this will be a custom audience you’ve created from customer information, Pixel or app data, or fans of your page. You can also create a new source at this point.

[image]

Note: Your source audiences need to contain at least 100 people from the same country. Facebook also generally recommends a source audience that has between 1,000-5,000 people, but high-quality sources take priority.

3. Select the countries or regions you would like to find a similar group of people. The areas you choose will determine where people in your Lookalike Audience are based, essentially adding a geo-filter onto your Lookalike Audience.

[image]

Note: You don’t have to have anyone from the country you want to target in your source.

4. Choose your desired audience size with the slide. Size is expressed on a scale of 1-10. Smaller numbers have a high similarity to your source audience. Meanwhile, larger numbers have higher reach but less similar characteristics. Facebook will provide you with an estimated reach for the size you choose.

You can also create multiple Lookalike Audiences with different levels of similarity to your source.

[image]

5. Click Create Audience. And you’re all set! It can take between six and 24 hours for your Lookalike Audience to be finished.

**Update**

There is actually a way of doing this with SFMC only. Once you used Journey Builder to configure you Advertising Audience (like below):
[image]

This audience gets created automatically in your Advertising Studio.
Then you need to edit it, and you have the option of adding a Lookalike audience based on it:
[image]

When you have configured this part, and saved the Audience, your lookalike audience appears next to your original audience from Journey Builder:

[image]

I will still recommend configuring your lookalikes in Facebook, as you get more tools to tweak and define your lookalike configuration.

Comment: Hi @lukas-lunow Thank You for the detailed response. Yeah its facebook and I did explore that option with the Ad Manager. But my ask is a little different. I want to use Journey Builder to post ads to Lookalikes. Like you can target a custom audience using JB, can we do the same for lookalikes? I created a Lookalike audience in Ad Studio in SFMC but then I want to use it in the Journey Builder

Comment: You can't use existing lookalike audience in JB, @Maneesh . Your audience is created when the JB activity is saved. Lookalike audiences, refresh settings, and email notifications can be modified from within Advertising Audiences after this audience is created.

Comment: Ahhh okay! Then how do you even use JB/ Ad Studio for new client acquisition? Or does it need to be done from within Ad Manager only?

Comment: @Maneesh - added details on how you can do this in SFMC

Comment: @lucas - thanks again! this is super helpful. I have one last Q - the lookalike audience that I created in Ad Studio do not appear in FB's Ad Manager. I can see the main audience but not the lookalike one. Is that an expected behavior?

Comment: @Maneesh - not sure about the reason, but this might be due to the audience being created for less than 24 hours ago, or perhaps not having enough contacts.

Comment: Thanks Lucas! Appreciate it